# Why the gradient generated doesn't get displayed?

Tags: html, css, gradient

As I copy the [generated gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#e4f5fc+0,bfe8f9+42,bfe8f9+46,9fd8ef+67,2ab0ed+100;Custom) :

```
background: #e4f5fc; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 42%, #bfe8f9 46%, #9fd8ef 67%, #2ab0ed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e4f5fc), color-stop(42%,#bfe8f9), color-stop(46%,#bfe8f9), color-stop(67%,#9fd8ef), color-stop(100%,#2ab0ed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e4f5fc 0%,#bfe8f9 42%,#bfe8f9 46%,#9fd8ef 67%,#2ab0ed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #e4f5fc 0%,#bfe8f9 42%,#bfe8f9 46%,#9fd8ef 67%,#2ab0ed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #e4f5fc 0%,#bfe8f9 42%,#bfe8f9 46%,#9fd8ef 67%,#2ab0ed 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e4f5fc 0%,#bfe8f9 42%,#bfe8f9 46%,#9fd8ef 67%,#2ab0ed 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e4f5fc', endColorstr='#2ab0ed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

to my `css` file, the gradient in the background is not generated and the background remains as it was. What could be the reason for this ? Is there anything else that needs to be done before ?

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: @j08691 sorry didn't get you. I copied the above css generated to the .css file but the background color didn't change

Comment: Post the HTML you're using this with, and any other CSS that might be interfering. A jsFiddle would help too.

Comment: My guess? Your element has no `height`.

Comment: Applying your code to a style rule (ex: `h1 { your stuff }` works fine. Thus the problem is not in the code you've posted. Please provide an example which demonstrates the problem without anything extraneous.

Answer (score -1):

Did you set any selector, to which this style shall be applied to?
E.g.

```
body{   
     background: .... /* all the stuff in here*/
}
```